# Map canada 6 digit zip codes on Looker

Tags: visualization, looker, mapview

Trying to visualize 6 digit zip codes of Canada on a map chart. But Looker is only supporting 3 digit zip codes to be mapped on the map.

How to map a zip code like `P0W 1L0` on Looker maps?
Looker is supporting only `P0W` to be mapped on the map.
Looker visualization based on the 3 digit zip code:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]